# Format negative currency values correctly with minus sign before the dollar sign

Tags: r, formatting, currency

I want to format negative currency values correctly with minus sign before the dollar sign.

The following code puts the minus sign after the dollar sign, i.e. $-100

```r
library(scales)
dollar(-100)
```

How would you change this to desired output i.e. -$100? 
I don't see an obvious option in documentation
https://rdrr.io/cran/scales/man/dollar_format.html

Comment: Here is an option with sprintf from another source for fixing the location of the negative sign, but then I need to deal with commas as thousands separators, and adjust whether i want cents,which I already do with scales, so if scales can do what is required, I'd rather not add the complexity of a different approach.  `x <- c(0.01,-0.01, 100000, -100)`
`ifelse(x>0, sprintf("$%4.2f", x), sprintf("-$%4.2f", abs(x)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the output of `dollar()` is a character vector you can define a new function using `chartr` on the results to conditionally swap the characters and use `...` to pass extra arguments to the original function.

```
library(scales)

newdollar <- function(x, ...) ifelse(x < 0, chartr("$-", "-$", dollar(x, ...)), dollar(x, ...))
newdollar(c(5, -5), suffix = "!!" )

[1] "$5!!"  "-$5!!"
```

Comment: Very nice! And for your average Joe, you might like to just put your options in the function, for example, whole dollars ... `dollaronly <- function(x) ifelse(x < 0, chartr("$-", "-$", dollar(x, accuracy = 1)), dollar(x, accuracy = 1))`      vs dollars and cents...  
`cents <- function(x) ifelse(x < 0, chartr("$-", "-$", dollar(x, accuracy = 0.01)), dollar(x, accuracy = 0.01))`

Answer (score 1):

One hacky way is to add a "-" sign explicitly to the absolute value of `amount` if `amount` is less than 0.

```
library(scales)
amount <- c(100, -200, -50)
ifelse(amount < 0, paste0("-", dollar(abs(amount))), dollar(amount))
#[1] "$100"  "-$200" "-$50"
```